# convert a vector to a list

Tags: r

I have a vector like this

```
 c("1", "a","b")
```

and I'd like to create this list

```
list("a"=1,"b"=1)
```

is there a way to do it in an "apply" style? Thanks.

-k

Comment: Hi Khanh -- one value, two labels?  That looks odd.

Comment: I need a quick look up, like a hash table. In this case, "a", and "b" are nodes in a network, and 1 is their community id. Is it efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
R> kn <- c("1", "a", "b")
R> nl <- vector(mode="list", length=length(kn)-1)
R> names(nl) <- kn[-1]
R> nl <- lapply(nl, function(x) kn[1])
R> nl
$a
[1] "1"

$b
[1] "1"

R>
```

With kudos to Gavin for spotting an earlier 
error.

Comment: @Dirk: `kn` doesn't have any names, and won't the `lapply` step overwrite `nl` so setting names before it won't make them stick?

Comment: Err, no, you were quite correct.  Fixed, re-ran and edited.  Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: names(nl) <- kn[-1] instead. Thanks.

Comment: It still needs `as.numeric(kn[1])` in the anonymous function - same problem I had with my answer that @Joshua Ulrich pointed out.

Comment: +1 --- Even with that extra `as.numeric()` your solution is a good deal faster than mine on the problem @knguyen posed.

Answer (score 12):

Using `as.list` and `setNames`:

```
x = c("1", "a","b")
as.list(setNames(rep(as.numeric(x[1]), length(x) - 1), x[-1]))
```

Comment: since I found this question while looking for a solution to the more general case of converting a vector to a named list, just wanted to add that you can also do this if you don't mind the names being the same as the contents: `as.list(setNames(x,x))`

Answer (score 5):

It isn't an apply style, but a simple function to wrap the required commands is:

```
makeList <- function(vec) {
    len <- length(vec[-1])
    out <- as.list(rep(as.numeric(vec[1]), len))
    names(out) <- as.character(vec[-1])
    out
}
```

Using your vector, it gives:

```
> vec <- c("1", "a","b")
> makeList(vec)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 1
```

Comment: Might want to `as.numeric` the "1"

Comment: @Joshua; woops! Well spotted.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, there is a simpler one-liner to do it in an "apply" style as requested:

```
as.list(sapply(x[-1],function(y) as.double(x[1])))
```

While not the fastest option, it is surely neat enough to deserve its place as an answer to the question. A significant speed-up is possible by not unnecessarily simplifying to a vector:

```
    library(microbenchmark)
    microbenchmark(times=20, 
               Charles=as.list(setNames(rep(as.numeric(x[1]), length(x) - 1), x[-1])),
               Gavin=makeList(x),
               Anon=sapply(x[-1],function(y) as.double(x[1]),simplify=FALSE)
)

Unit: microseconds
    expr    min      lq median      uq    max neval
 Charles 10.868 11.7735 11.774 12.3775 55.848    20
   Gavin 12.075 12.6795 13.132 13.8870 26.867    20
    Anon  6.643  7.0950  7.548  8.1520 17.811    20
```

Comment: Rather than `as.list(sapply(...))`, use `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)`.

Comment: Without simplify=F, we'll have identical(Charles,Anon)=FALSE, which I didn't want. With simplify=F, your suggestion leads to further speed-up --- I've updated my answer. Thanks.