# How to decide which dataframes will be bundled into a list, based on dataframe-specific conditions

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements

I have several dataframes that I want to merge. I'm looking for a scalable solution and I've found [this nice one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34393416/6105259). So I do:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df_a <- data.frame(id = 1:8)
df_b <- data.frame(id = 5:10)
df_c <- data.frame(id = 2:6)
df_d <- data.frame(id = 3:6)

dfs_to_merge <- list(df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d)

dfs_to_merge %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = "id")
#>   id
#> 1  1
#> 2  2
#> 3  3
#> 4  4
#> 5  5
#> 6  6
#> 7  7
#> 8  8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But what if, for example, I wanted to condition whether `df_c` will be included in `dfs_to_merge` based on a the value of a variable `my_condition_df_c`?

### Example — Not a scalable solution

If `my_condition_df_c > 5` then include `df_c` in `dfs_to_merge`

```r
my_condition_df_c <- sample(1:10, 1)

if (my_condition_df_c > 5) {
  dfs_to_merge <- list(df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d)
} else {
  dfs_to_merge <- list(df_a, df_b, df_d)
}

dfs_to_merge %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = "id")
```

### My Problem

Consider that I may have several dataframes to merge, and that each one of them may have its own condition that determines whether it should be passed forward for merging.

```r
my_condition_df_a <- sample(1:100, 1) ## include df_a if my_condition_df_a > 65                      
my_condition_df_b <- sample(c("foo", "blah"), 1) ## include df_b if my_condition_df_b == "foo"       
my_condition_df_d <- sample(c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA, 19), 1) ## include df_d if my_condition_df_d is not NA
```

How could I elegantly condition which data frame gets in and which is not? Using if-else blocks as I did above is not a scalable solution as it will easily become messy and unreadable code.

---

**UPDATE — I made some progress**

---

So what I do is to make a character vector of object names, containing the names of dataframes to be included in the list later (or not). Being included in this vector is subject to specific condition per data frame.

```r
dfs_to_merge_names <- c()

if (my_condition_df_a > 65) {
  dfs_to_merge_names <- c(dfs_to_merge_names, "df_a")
} 

if (my_condition_df_b == "foo") {
  dfs_to_merge_names <- c(dfs_to_merge_names, "df_b")
} 

if (my_condition_df_c > 5) {
  dfs_to_merge_names <- c(dfs_to_merge_names, "df_c")
} 

if (!is.na(my_condition_df_d)) {
  dfs_to_merge_names <- c(dfs_to_merge_names, "df_d")
} 

mget(dfs_to_merge_names) %>% ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/45963957/6105259
  reduce(left_join, by = "id")
```

I will still be happy for ideas whether this code could be shortened and more concise.

Comment: There is nothing in the `dfs_to_merge` to suggest which of your sporadic `_condition_`s would be appropriate for which frame. That is, if `character` then compare with `"foo"`, but if `integer` then either compare with `65` or `!is.na`. You're going to have to devise a way to determine that side yourself. Once you have that, let's say all of that reduces to `my_conditions` which is a `logical` for each element of your list, then you can do `reduce(dfs_to_merge[my_conditions], left_join, by = "id")`.

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for commenting. I'm not sure I understand your point though. I updated my question, maybe it brings me closer to what you've said? In any case, my update is in the spirit of the solution I'm hoping to find, if that's helpful in any way...

Answer (score 2):

Here's stab that avoids the use of `mget`.

```r
conditions <- c(
  (my_condition_df_a > 65),
  (my_condition_df_b == "foo"),
  (my_condition_df_c > 5),
  (!is.na(my_condition_df_d))
)
reduce(dfs_to_merge[conditions], left_join, by = "id")
```

An alternative, if you are not assured of the order of conditions versus frames in the list. Build your list of frames *named*, either manually or with `lst`:

```r
dfs_to_merge <- list(df_a=df_a, df_b=df_b, df_c=df_c, df_d=df_D) # names can be anything
dfs_to_merge <- lst(df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d)                      # names will be object's symbols
```

Then using your condition-building:

```r
dfs_to_merge_names <- c()

if (my_condition_df_a > 65) {
  dfs_to_merge_names <- c(dfs_to_merge_names, "df_a")
}
# ...
reduce(dfs_to_merge[dfs_to_merge_names ], left_join, by = "id")
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm a bit confused about the second approach. We first set up `dfs_to_merge <- lst(df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d)` and then build `dfs_to_merge_names` with `if` blocks, but at the end we don't use `dfs_to_merge_names` but rather `dfs_to_merge[conditions]`?

Comment: just a thought, would have it been simpler/more concise if we had first organized this information in a table, where one column is for *names* of dataframes, and another column is for the condition? This way, we have the mapping of which condition pertains to what dataframe, and we can iterate over this? I'm wary of code that relies on order because of the possible risk of mismatches. Thus, your first suggestion is something I'd typically avoid. Leaving us with your second suggestion, which isn't really more concise than my `mget` solution (we still use `if` blocks).

Comment: referring to my previous comment, I'm demonstrating such a table: `df_names_and_conditions <- tibble::tribble(~df_name, ~condition, "df_a", sample(1:100, 1) > 65, "df_b", sample(c("foo", "blah"), 1) == "foo", "df_c", sample(1:10, 1) > 5, "df_d", sample(c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA, 19), 1))
`